# (Bootstrap) - Changing dropdown button text to reflect item clicked removes caret

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the dropdown from bootstrap and i would like the button to have its text change depending on which of it's two dropdown items i click. The text changes according to the item clicked but the caret is gone after the first change and so forth. I want to keep the caret in the button!

```
 <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

  <body>
  <div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value="Fast">Fast
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" value="Fast">
  <li onclick="dropdown(this.innerHTML);">Fast</li>
  <li onclick="dropdown(this.innerHTML);">Accurate</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
function dropdown(val){
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default dropdown-toggle');
var aNode = y[0].innerHTML=val;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your current code, appending the caret icon code will help you retain it after changing the drop down value.

```js
function dropdown(val) {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default dropdown-toggle');
  var aNode = y[0].innerHTML = val + ' <span class="caret"></span>'; // Append 
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value="Fast">Fast
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" value="Fast">
      <li onclick="dropdown(this.innerHTML);">Fast</li>
      <li onclick="dropdown(this.innerHTML);">Accurate</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I tried exactly that before asking this question but i apparently forgot to add single quotes around the span. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it happens :) Just try to check your console in future for the errors.

Comment: Just a small caveat with this:  you now have the icon defined in two places.  If, for whatever reason, you decide to use a different icon from the 'caret' (eg 'glyphicon-circle-arrow-down') then you'll have to change it in both places.  It's best practice to avoid recreating existing html via js - but if it works in this case and you're happy with that, then no worries.

Answer (score 3):

`.innerHTML` will get you the entire content, including the inner `span` that you are using for the caret.

What you need is the `textContent` of the `firstchild` of your dropdown, which is actually a textNode.

***Example Snippet***:

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')[0],
    options = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu')[0]
;

options.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
      dropdown.firstChild.textContent = e.target.textContent + ' ';
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dropdownBtn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Fast <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Fast</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Accurate</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use innerText in the dropdown function instead of innerHTML

```
<li onclick="dropdown(this.innerText);">Fast</li>
```

Change the content of the function to replace the textContent of the firstChild which holds the value of the button.

```
var aNode = y[0].firstChild.textContent = val;
```

```js
function dropdown(val) {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default dropdown-toggle');
  var aNode = y[0].firstChild.textContent = val; 
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value="Fast">Fast
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" value="Fast">
      <li onclick="dropdown(this.innerText);">Fast</li>
      <li onclick="dropdown(this.innerText);">Accurate</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're replacing the *html* with the value - the caret span is *inside* the button (so part of the html of the button), so also getting replaced.

As you're using bootstrap, which uses jquery, use jquery to make this easy:

```
function dropdown(val) {
    $(".btn.dropdown-toggle").text(val) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the caret inside a variable and add it back when you change the value.
As you are using bootstrap, you already have jQuery loaded in the page so let's do it this way:

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86w427eq/1/)

```js
$myDropdown = $('#MyDropdown');
$myDropdown.find("li").click(function(){
$caret = ' <span class="caret"></span>';
$val = $(this).html();
$(".btn.dropdown-toggle").html($val+$caret)
});
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value="Fast">Fast
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul id="MyDropdown" class="dropdown-menu" value="Fast">
  <li>Fast</li>
  <li>Accurate</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the one and only permanent solution for bootstrap 3.This will work for all dropdown.

```
<head>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <!-- jQuery library -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value="Fast">Fast
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li>Fast</li>
         <li>Accurate</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <script>
      $(document).on('click','.dropdown-menu li',function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').html($(this).html()  + ' <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>');
      });
   </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```